# node.js not printing to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to use sockets in my api. However I could not see the logs in the console.

The only output I see is:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
We are live on8000
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
// server.js
const express        = require('express');
const MongoClient    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const app            = express();
const port           = 8000;

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

const db = require('./config/db');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../app'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


MongoClient.connect(db.url,(err,database) =>{

    if (err) return console.log(err);

    //check below line changed
     require('./app/routes')(app, database);
    app.listen(port,() => {
        console.log("We are live on"+port);
    });

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });


    io.on('connection',function(socket){
      console.log('client connected');

      socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('disconnect');
      });

    });

})
```

and the index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Hello world</title></head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
  <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

I see Hello world on the web browser, but I could not see 'client connected' on the console log.

Comment: That is what I have.When the console prints 'We are live on8000'', doesn't it mean server is connected ? Could you please tell me how can I connect to server ?

Comment: @JaromandaX calling the socket.io on port 3000 prints the logs. But calling it on port 8000 doesn't print the logs. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: In your browser client you can see error in console.log `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js  404` and `(index):6 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`

You have attach `socket handler` to a http server `var io = require('socket.io')(server);`, but in your code you start web server by `express server`

```
app.listen(port,() => {
        console.log("We are live on"+port);
    });
```

change it to

```
server.listen(port,() => {
        console.log("We are live on"+port);
    });
```

Comment: My client is Android and iOS apps. But node server does not output any of the console.logs that are under io.on()

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new .js file and listening to port 3000 instead of 8000 worked for socket.io

appsocket.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('A user connected');

  //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('A user disconnected');
  });

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Now I am able to see the logs on console when I call localhost:3000 instead of localhost:8000

Comment: do you see how different this server code is to the original? that's why it works

Comment: indeed - I didn't see the problem either :p